# Network Error when Looking for Smart Groups

Tags: smartgroups

Under the groups tab in a contact summary if we click to view the smart groups the contact is in we get:

Network Error
Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

We have checked the setting for URLs & Directories & cleared the cache. If we do a search for contacts in the a smart group all is fine. Below is the error & backtrace from the log.

Install is WordPress 5.4 and CiviCRM 5.23.4.

```
 [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(192): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(998): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#3 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#4 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1925): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(935): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...", "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#7 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(405): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1231): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#9 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2691): DB_common->query("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#10 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#11 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(421): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#12 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1497): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...", TRUE)
#13 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(569): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   \nLEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id ...")
#14 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(3191): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::load(Object(CRM_Core_DAO))
#15 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(3092): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->addGroupContactCache((Array:1), "civicrm_group_contact_cache_5e8dc68a3c7d6", "contact_a", "IN")
#16 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1819): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->group((Array:5))
#17 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2057): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle((Array:5), FALSE)
#18 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(581): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(FALSE)
#19 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(528): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(NULL)
#20 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4614): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct((Array:1), (Array:1), (Array:24), TRUE, FALSE, 1, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, "AND", NULL, "1")
#21 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(210): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::apiQuery((Array:1), (Array:1), NULL, NULL, 0, 0, FALSE)
#22 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(192): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::add((Array:21))
#23 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/GroupContactCache.php(688): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::loadAll()
#24 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/ContactSmartGroup.php(41): CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::contactGroup("9445")
#25 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/ContactSmartGroup.php(89): CRM_Contact_Page_View_ContactSmartGroup->browse()
#26 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(268): CRM_Contact_Page_View_ContactSmartGroup->run((Array:4), NULL)
#27 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#28 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#29 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1449): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#30 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#31 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#32 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#33 /home/<<account>>/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(254): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#34 {main}


 [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   
LEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id = .id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
                          SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
                          WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
                          AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 17 )  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON .entity_id = .id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN ' at line 2]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   
LEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id = .id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
                          SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
                          WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
                          AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 17 )  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON .entity_id = .id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN ' at line 2]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a   
LEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id = .id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
                          SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
                          WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
                          AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 17 )  [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON .entity_id = .id  WHERE (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN ' at line 2]"]
)
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN  ON .entity_id` part is a clue. It seems like maybe you have a smart group that references a deleted custom field group or something like that? I would try editing and resaving the smart group (group id 17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sql and backtrace, it looks like it is trying to rebuild the smart group id 17. Try resaving the group id 17 search criteria.

Comment: Yep I was thinking same thing.

Comment: That was the issue. The criteria on smart group id 17 was referencing a disabled custom field. The group was not in use so I disabled it and all is good now. Thanks